# Stormpath integration with existing spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, stormpath

I have a spring boot app which has spring boot security enabled on it.
The table I have used UserAccount and Role. Now I want to integrate stormpath for access control. How can I migrate my existing system with stormpath? My security configuration is given below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
     @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.csrf().disable();

         http
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/*", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/school-admin/*").hasAuthority("SCHOOL_ADMIN").anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
             .antMatchers("/teacher/*").hasAuthority("TEACHER").anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
             .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

         .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login.html").defaultSuccessUrl("/loginSuccess.html")
            .failureUrl("/login.html?error").permitAll().and()

         .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout.html")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html?logout");

     }

     @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you already have a Stormpath account? If so, it should be as easy as adding a dependency to the Spring Boot Starter and using a `WebSecurityConfig` similar to the one you're using. You'll likely have to remove your `CustomUserDetailsService` and `configureGlobal` method. For the authorities, you can create groups in Stormpath. You also won't need to specify `.formLogin()` or `.logout()` since Stormpath provides those.

Comment: Yes, I have stormpath account. The users and roles are in stormpath server. In my case users are on my server. Then how it will be authenticated, and if new user is registered it will be on my server not on stormpath server.